# Quais os procedimentos a adotar para implementar a interoperabilidade semântica de um Web Service REST?

Tags: rest

A interoperabilidade semântica é algo facultativo no padrão REST, não há regras definidas como ocorre no SOAP com o WSDL - por exemplo, mas entendo que no REST é importante manter assim para tornar o padrão flexível, pelo menos se tratando de especificação.

Entretanto para um serviço consistente, é necessário implementar procedimentos para que a comunicação entre os sistemas seja o mais transparente possível.

**Quais os procedimentos a adotar para implementar a interoperabilidade semântica de um Web Service REST?**

Comment: O que quer dizer com interoperabilidade nesse caso?

Comment: *A interoperabilidade é uma das grandes desvantagens de um Web Service que usa REST*. É uma das grandes desvantagens mesmo? Tem como explicar isso?

Comment: Talvez: "O problema de interoperabilidade é real?"

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Da maneira como está enunciada, a sua pergunta assume como um fato comprovado que existe um problema de interoperabilidade. Muitos profissionais acham justamente o contrário.

Comment: @OnoSendai e é fato comprovado que não existe um problema de interoperabilidade semântica? Porque isso seria o que você diz ser "justamente o contrário". Temos que concordar que teria que fazer a pergunta a tender para um lado ou para o outro, uma vez que meio termo seria uma pergunta baseada em opiniões, certo?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Por isso que em muitos casos as perguntas são realizadas em cascata. "O problema X é real? Caso sim, como mitigá-lo?" Se X não for real (e a resposta é binária, sim ou não), então não há porque responder a segunda pergunta.

Comment: @OnoSendai eu discordo, para mim o problema é real, não é algo obrigatório no padrão REST, o que não ocorre no SOAP - por exemplo - uma vez que temos o WSDL. Ok, talvez essa flexibilidade não seja um problema justamente por permitir o programador escolher entre implementar soluções. O que gostaria é de conhecer essas soluções, tal como no SOAP existe o WSDL. Editei a pergunta e removi o termo "problema".

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio editei a pergunta e adicionei "semântica".